# Shell script to set environment variables permanently

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I need to write a shell script to set environment variable and modify path variable  permanently. Is there in any way to modify bashrc file through script?

Comment: You can edit the `bashrc` or you can call your script that sets the variables from `bashrc`.  If you run the script as in `. script_to_set_vars`, the vars will last for that session only.  Why would you want to modify `bashrc` through script?

Comment: @vpit3833 A natural reason for modifying `.bashrc` variables through script is when creating an installation script, for which symlinks cannot be created.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you write a script that appends to .bashrc with the >> redirection operator:

```
echo Your Text >> ~/.bashrc
```

See also [I/O Redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)

Comment: This will not update the variables already present in `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer modifying  the .bashrc file directly

Answer (score 0):

**Is there in any way to modify bashrc file through script?**, you don't need to do that.

Just manually set the required variable in **.bashrc** once that will do.

Comment: A natural reason for modifying .bashrc variables through script is when creating an installation script, for which symlinks cannot be created. Instead of asking the user to modify the variables in the script, it could be much easier to do it by launching a script (in theory).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general. You should specify what kind of changes you need to make. What some answerers don't seem to imagine is that you might need to script this in order to make changes to multiple accounts on a system, for example.

In general, you can use any technique that you would use on any other text file. One way would be to use `sed`.